# Remapping power and volume keys

Tags: sony-xperia, buttons

My power button has broken so I'm trying to use the volume up key as the power button instead. My phone is a rooted Sony Xperia Go ST27i running Android 4.1.2.

I've tried [ButtonRemapper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464), but this does not work on my phone so I'm trying to do it manually.

The output of `$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices` contains:

```
Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
Name="ux500-ske-keypad"
```

So I thought I'd edit the `/system/usr/keylayout/ux500-ske-keypad.kl` file, however this file does not contain what I expected.

It has no config for a power button and contains only the two lines:

```
key115  VOLUME_UP   WAKE
key114  VOLUME_DOWN WAKE
```

So nowhere I can disable the power button (assume this is key 116 on this model?). Also neither of the volume keys work to wake my phone, so is this config file even being read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering own question in case anybody else has the same issue.

There is another file `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl` that contained the mapping for the power button. The Android docs say never to modify this file but I did anyway. Commenting out the power button line in this file has solved my issue (power button stuck in) and I'm now using my volume up button as the power button.

Note that I also had to remount the `/system` partition as read-write that I did with the excellent [FX app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx)