# Disable Volume and Power button screenshot

Tags: buttons, screenshots

Pressing Volume (-Up or -Down) and Power button takes automatic screenshot. 
Can I disable this feature? 
(I often grab my phone and press those buttons by mistake).

I use OnePlus with OxygenOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, you unfortunately can't unless your phone is rooted. A user submitted a suggestion to have [Option to disable screenshot using volume down and power button](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/option-to-disable-screenshot-using-volume-down-and-power-button.1010008/page-3) for OnePlus 6T. On the same thread, there are also owners of other OnePlus models asking for the same.

If your phone is rooted, you can disable the package `com.oneplus.screenshot` although it will introduce the [disadvantage](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=80037591&postcount=2) of no longer being able to take screentshots.

You can also try to remap the keys as shown [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106891/247431).